# Show "show more" button and hide second line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm totally lost here. I'm trying to display information on my website on only using one line of text. If more info need to be shown, the extra info will be shown on second line. But how can I hide the second line and show a button "show more" instead?

Once the user clicks on the show more button, the extra info/texts on second line will only be shown. Thanks...

Below is my javascript for the button, I have no idea how to code the html part where the second line will be hidden automatically and display the "show more" button.

```
var hide2 = 1;    
$('#showmorerates').click(function(){
            if(hide2 == 1){
                $('.morerates').toggle(300);
                document.getElementById("showmorerates").innerHTML = '<a>Show Less</a>';
                hide2 = 0;
            } else {
                $('.morerates').toggle(300);
                document.getElementById("showmorerates").innerHTML = '<a>Show More</a>';
                hide2 = 1;
            }
    });
```

Comment: What about having a div with hidden overflow attribute so that the information does not scroll down but only 1 line of information can be shown if the height of the div is equal to line-height. Then, you can have a show more button below that div. Once clicked, height of the div can be set to larger value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a css class to set height of the div and overflow to hidden. Whenever `show more` button is clicked, remove this class from the text container.

```
.less {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 1em;
}
```

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2tg7v/

Comment: This is really close to what I want, but how can I hide the button, if all info can be shown in one line?

Answer (score 1):

Refer this plugin: http://jrvis.com/trunk8/

Use:

```
$('.morerates').trunk8({
  lines: 1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should not be difficult to pull off. You can do something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    // when more button is clicked
    $('#more').click(function(){
        text = $(this).attr("data-text");
        $('#more-text').toggle(function(){
            if(text == "more"){
                $('#more').text("Less");
                $('#more').attr("data-text","less");
            } else {
                $('#more').text("More");
                $('#more').attr("data-text","more");
            }

        });
    });
});
```

See jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8jFGc/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code. Make sure u called Jquery Script First.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<style>
    ul{list-style:none;}
    p{border:1px solid;}
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#tab > p").hide();

        $("#tab h1").click(function(){
            $("#tab >p ").slideUp(0);
            //$(this).siblings("p").slideDown();            
            $(this).parent().children("p").slideDown(0);
        });

    });
</script>

<style>

    p{
        width:35%;
    }
</style>
    <div id="tab">
        <h1> Hello </h1>
        <p> Hello PAra Hello PAraHello PAraHello PAraHello </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab">
        <h1> Hello 1</h1>
        <p> Hello PAra Hello PAraHello PAraHello PAraHello </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: I want something like @qamyoncu ... just left the hide button when there's only one line of text to show.